# Cant find protocol variable in apache RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rule below in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/?http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,R=302,L]
```

But I would like to redirect the user based in the protocol used (HTTP or HTTPS). I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/?%{SERVER_PROTOCOL}://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,R=302,L]
```

But the user gets redirected to "https://example.com/?HTTP/1.1://example.com/anything?anything"

I dont want to use RewriteCond for a simple task like this, is there any variable that I can use for this, I mean, that return http OR https? I checked here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html but I am not sure if there is one.

Comment: Do you mean %{REQUEST_SCHEME} ?

Comment: YEAP :) Please post an answer I will approve, thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

Because I asked user @starkeen to post his comment as an answer and he didnt post it, I am publishing it here. For capturing the HTTP or HTTPS part of the protocol used you could use %{REQUEST_SCHEME}.

However I dont advise using it cause I tried it and it is buggy, in some cases even using HTTPS it belies it's using HTTP so you should use other alternatives online.